# «Мечта» во множественном числе

Tags: склонение, морфология

Как правильно писать это слово в р. п. мн. числа? Извините, не знаю правильную метку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Мечт,* безусловно, неправильно. Но и предложенное Ожеговым мечтание все-таки, на мой взгляд, от мечты отличается. Мечта - вроде неопределенной цели, образ, а мечтания - это процесс грез об этой мечте. Лучше пользоваться описательным оборотом. Если это пожелания, то вместо "желаю исполнения мечт" лучше написать "желаю, чтобы все твои мечты сбылись" или "пусть Ваши мечты сбудутся".

Comment: Почему неправильно, тем более безусловно?

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение. Я считаю, что множественное число "мечт" стоит избегать заменяя его.

Answer (score 10):

Множественное число, естественно, "мечтЫ". Проблема возникает в родительном падеже множественоного числа. По общей схеме должно быть "мечт", но такой вариант обычно отвергается по фонетическим соображениям.

Вместе с тем его нельзя считать абсолютно неправильным, такие формы (мечт - к мечта и тахт - к тахта) следует классифицировать как *несвободные*, но не неграмотные.

Формы "мечтаний" - это не родительный падеж как таковой, это замена на синоним, увы не такой уж и точный, хотя и похоже звучащий. Надо десять раз подумать, чтобы выбрать именно его. Боюсь, что в разговорной речи именно "мечт" (и "тахт") будет более правильным. В строго нормируемой речи лучше просто избегать предложений, требующих употребления родительного множественного для "мечта".

Answer (score 1):

"Мечта" во множественном числе - мечты. Словарь Ожегова предлагает в родительном  падеже множественного числа употреблять "мечтаний"

Comment: исполнение МЕЧТ (если их несколько)?

Comment: Словарь Ожегова предлагает в родительном падеже множественного числа употреблять "мечтаний"

Answer (score 1):

Нет, писать "сбыча мечт" явно неправильно, но как люди ухитряются, нарочито это употребляют, показывая, что понимают, что это неправильно, хотя сами не знают, как писать. Считаю, что нельзя употреблять "мечта" во множественном числе в родительном падеже. Ожегов тоже неправ, "мечтаний" скорее описывает процесс, чем мечты. Ведь тогда "сбывание мечтаний", это звучит хуже чем "сбыча мечт" и уж точно описывает процесс мечтаний, а не мечты. Не хочу сказать, что русский язык плох, просто есть сочетания, слов которых следует избегать. Такие казусы есть во всех языках.

Answer (score -1):

Слово МЕЧТА абсолютно точно не имеет формы Р.п.;мн.ч.
Мы на уроке проверяли и вариант МЕЧТ оказался неправильным

Comment: Мы на уроке проверяли... Так проверили? Как?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?